# Disable suggestions for EditText

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-emulator, android-edittext

What I have tried:

specifying the inputType for the EditText on the main.xml page as...

```
textFilter
text|textNoSuggestions 
textNoSuggestions
```

In the java file in the onCreate

```
EditText hex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editHex);
hex.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

I'm running this on an emulator using API 13.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me after a long struggle...
Use just `android:inputType="textFilter"`, and remove the `hex.setInputType()` , it replaces what you configured 
in your XML at runtime.

If it still doesn't work you can always try the dirty trick of `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`, but I strongly suggest that you give `android:inputType="textFilter"` another try.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear enough: I tried all of those individually.

Comment: I kept looking for ways to make it work, and since I failed to do so, I went with your suggestion of using textVisiblePassword.

Comment: This doesn't work. Autosuggestion box still remains there. And textVisiblePassword hides emoji box, not good.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` worked in Android 5+ phones, but for Android 4 I had to set visible password via code, using this method:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: I tried different combinations for the xml attributes and none of them were working. Apparently setting it programatically is the only way to get it working for some devices or at least for my custom EditText. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works for me when i put:
android:importantForAutofill="no" in editText field.

Happy coding :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31063401)